# Apache ENV var not being set in mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This sets the query string value `q` to the request uri (stripping any preceding directories before the one that index.php resides in).

For example: `http://localhost/framework/testing` sets `q=testing`.

I would like to change this so that instead of setting a query string, I would like to set an environment variable. I have tried the following but it does not work (the environment var does not get set):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [ENV=request:$1,L]
</IfModule>
```

Oddly enough, the environment var will get set if the request starts with index.php, for example: `http://localhost/framework/index.php/testing` sets `q=index.php/testing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PATH_INFO (as suggested by @chrono) and slightly different mod_rewrite rules I've got things working as desired!

Modified .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can check your answer as valid now ;)

Comment: I suppose; it answers the question I asked but it doesn't work on aliased urls (shared ssl). My aim is to not have to specify a base URL in my PHP.

Comment: So well, errr... modify your question, or check this one as valid and maybe ask another one?